# How to set Thumbnail Image in video?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, alassetslibrary

In application, i record a video using camera. Now when i save this video in the phone library, it saved and by default first frame of video is saved as thumbnail image for that video. When we display saved video in gallery it display the thumbnail image for that video(first frame of video).

Now the problem is that, I need to change this thumbnail image for the video, as before saving video, fpr each second, 1 frames is displayed in scroll view. If i select last second frame as thumbnail image, then this selected frame be displayed as thumbnail image in library.
 Any suggestion also be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to make a still image from a video taken to display in an app view. I realise you may be talking only of when it's saved within the device's photo library, in which case I'm not sure if this will work for you, but I hope it helps. The AVFoundation framework is likely to be the best bet to find a solution.

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:yourVideoURL options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
CGImageRef oneRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
UIImage *videoStill = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:oneRef];
[imageView videoStill];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Cheers, Jim.

Comment: This is not my question. I didn't need to extract still image from video. I have that, i need to set a particular still image as a cover/poster image for the video in library.